# Keras ZeroPadding layer won't work dynamically

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras, keras-layer

I'm trying to use such architecture for bottleneck

```
Input
\/
MaxPooling2D
\/
Conv2D
\/
UpSampling
\/
Output
```

Such that output would have same shape as input no matter what is input shape.

I've already tried using UpSampling2D and then adding padding. It looked like this

```
input_ = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(13, 13, 1))
mp = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D()(input_)
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(1, (3, 3), padding='same')(mp)
up = tf.keras.layers.UpSampling2D()(x)

x_pad = tf.cond(input_.shape[1] != None, lambda: input_.shape[1] - up.shape[1], lambda: 0)
y_pad = tf.cond(input_.shape[2] != None, lambda: input_.shape[2] - up.shape[2], lambda: 0)

padding = tf.keras.layers.ZeroPadding2D(padding=((x_pad, 0), (y_pad, 0)))(up)
```

Everything works fine for even and odd input sizes, but when input is declared like

```
input_ = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(None, None, 1))
```

No matter what input I give, there is always no padding at all

Comment: Your conditional states if the shapes are not None, then apply padding, otherwise don't apply padding. When your input is (None, None, 1) why would you not expect this to evaluate the second clause of your condition?

Comment: This statement is only because of that when Keras is building graph, those shapes are None and it would throw error if I'd apply padding None. So the only purpose of this is not to throw error at compiling. But when calling `fit` shape of input tensor shouldn't be None.